compiler complaining that memory is uninitialized
I am writing a class that is supposed to read a config file and fill a map that contains the configs.
While reading the file, reading algorithm uses a pointer to an enum class which contains different config names, but it is throwing an Access Violation, and the compiler complains that it is using uninitialized memory.
As a solution, I turned the pointer to a simple variable, but the results are the same, the compiler now complains that the variable is uninitialized!
Here is the function that reads the file:
std::map<const char*, Config> conf_str_table = {
    { "screen_size", Config::screen_size },
    { "window_name", Config::window_name },
    { "cam_mov", Config::cam_mov },
};

void FileManager::GetConfigFromFile()
{
    std::ifstream* tmp = new std::ifstream(config_file_name);
    std::string* current_line = new std::string;
    std::pair<Config, std::string>* current_config = new std::pair<Config, std::string>;

    if (tmp->is_open()) {
        while (std::getline(*tmp, *current_line)) {

            // ignoring comments
            if (current_line->at(0) == '#')
                continue;

            bool is_reading_value = false;

            std::string* tmp_conf = new std::string;
            std::string* tmp_value = new std::string;

            for (auto c : *current_line) {

                if (c == ' ')
                    continue;

                if (c == '=') {
                    is_reading_value = true;
                    continue;
                }

                if (is_reading_value) {
                    tmp_value->push_back(c);
                } else {
                    tmp_conf->push_back(c);
                }
            }
            Config* conf_ptr = new Config;

            if (auto search = conf_str_table.find(tmp_conf->c_str()); search != conf_str_table.end()) {
                *conf_ptr = search->second;
            } else {
            }
            delete tmp_conf;
            current_config->first = *conf_ptr;
            current_config->second = *tmp_value;
            delete tmp_value;
        }
        delete current_line;
        delete current_config;
    } else {
        
    }
    delete tmp;
}

Here is the class (most of these are not fully implemented yet):
#pragma once

#include "raywin.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <raylib.h>
#include <vector>

constexpr const char* config_file_name = "config.cfg";

enum class Config {
    screen_size,
    window_name,
    cam_mov,
};

enum class Config_Error {
    property_not_found,
    config_file_not_found,
};

struct FileManager {
    /*
         CANNOT throw exceptions !
         if an error occurs it will load
         default settings and notify the user
 */
    void GetConfigFromFile();
    int GetInt(std::string& key);
    std::string GetString(std::string& key);
    double GetDouble(std::string& key);
    Vector2 GetVector2(std::string& key);
    void ErrorUseDefaultConfig(Config_Error& err);

private:
    std::map<Config, std::string> values = {
        { Config::screen_size, "1920x1080" },
        { Config::window_name, "Untitled" },
        { Config::cam_mov, "0.05" },
    };
};

The error occurs on conf_ptr.

Please copy and paste full error message you get (as text, not as image).

Also, a rant, but why do you use all these new? It's just asking for trouble.

there is never a good reason to dynamically allocate a std::string or std::ifstream

well since these are temporary variables wouldn't it make sense to remove them as soon as they are not used anymore?

@BardiaBahrampour No. Heap memory allocations are costly. Stack allocations are cheap. Not to mention that your computer has enough memory to hold millions of such objects, so you don't have to worry about recycling it unless you are coding for a tiny embedded device. From code style perspective, if you find yourself using too many local variables, that's a good sign you should split your function into smaller, more focused functions.

Why new std::ifstream(config_file_name);? There is no reason to do that in your code. This way you've made code more bug prone. std::ifstream tmp(config_file_name); would do a better job.

Where is conf_str_table?

std::string* tmp_conf = new std::string; is odd.  std::string itself is already a smart pointer that specializes in string semantics.  Why would you have a raw pointer to a smart pointer?  If there is legit use case, why isn't it std::unique_ptr<std::string> or std::optional<std::string> instead?

Aside: why not struct Config { Vector2 screen_size; std::string window_name; double cam_mov; };? Then a free function std::expected<Config, ConfigError> GetConfigFromFIle();?

[mcve], please?

Side note: On a tiny embedded device you likely don't have a virtual memory manager with all of its bells and whistles. This has the potential to make using new even more dangerous.

Does Config* conf_ptr = new Config{Config:: screen_size}; solve your problem?

So, you have the following construct:
T* pointer = new T;
if( something1 )
    *pointer = something2;
else
    delete pointer;
something3 = *pointer;

So clearly, there is a possible sequence of events where pointer is allocated, then soomething1 is false, so the else branch is chosen, so pointer is immediately deallocated, (not a very smart thing to do,) and then you proceed to read the value pointed by pointer into something3.  Of course this will read garbage, and of course the compiler is warning you about this.
EDIT
(After some clarifications in the comments)
Since you are using enum class, this means you are using C++ 11 or higher.
In C++ 11 or higher, according to this answer:

new T is default initialisation. For aggregate classes such as Line and Point this means that all sub objects are default initialised. For primitive objects such as double* and int this means no initialisation. If an object isn't initialised1, then it has an indeterminate value. This means that their value is indeterminate. If a program reads an indeterminate value (of a type other than narrow character type), then the behaviour of the program is undefined. This is to be avoided. Don't do this.

Apparently, an enum class is a "primitive object", so, as user @Eljay said in a comment, you should do Config* conf_ptr = new Config { Config::screen_size };

you are right, this was an oversight, however, when i removed the delete statement it is still giving the same warning

Tell us what is the exact text of the warning, and show us on precisely which source line the warning is issued.

C6001: Using uninitialized memory '*conf_ptr'

on. precisely. which. source. line. is. this. given.

current_config->first = *conf_ptr;
Line 55 in the source file

@BardiaBahrampour Don't just remove the deletes, remove all the news too. You need approximately 0 instances of new in a C++ program

@Caleth would it be better to use smart pointers instead?

@BardiaBahrampour no, you don't need pointers for this. see here

Config* conf_ptr = new Config; does not initialize the value pointed to by *conf_ptr.  Config* conf_ptr = new Config{Config:: screen_size}; would initialize it.
